# How to declare internal scope constant in Swift?

Tags: swift

How do you define internal scope, global string in Swift?

```
static NSString *globalString = @"globalString";

@implementation MyViewController

...

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so using a "private" global variable:

```
private globalString = "globalString"
```

Private restricts access to the variable to only within the same file.

Comment: Actually, you cannot yet define a class scope constant. But as of Swift 1.0, you can now define variables with internal scope.

Comment: @nschum, thanks for pointing this out (I originally answered this before access controls where introduced). I updated my answer.